# Printing table design in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, printing

I am using Access 2013, and would like to know if this enables the printing of table designs (fields names, field types, comments if needed, etc...) ?  I have been using Snipping Tool to copy the design to jpg or to a document, especially when wanting to get a listing of a table with many fields, but there should be a quicker way.  I did search for this topic in the other StackOverflow forums, but did not see any references to actually printing table designs....If there is one, then please point me to it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Database Documenter in the Database Tools ribbon does this.